# How to find the amount of upvotes on a reddit post

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
    import results as results
    import soup as soup
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import os, os.path, csv

    from sqlalchemy.sql.operators import div

    page = requests.get(URL)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    UpvoteCount = results.find('section',div._1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO)

    print(results.prettify())

    print(soup.style)
```

i want to find the amount of upvotes on a reddit post and I found the section of code that does that
(it's an html website but my code is in python):

```
    <div class="_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO" style="color: rgb(215, 218, 220);">1</div>
```

the important one i want to find is the div part >1

the style is what i want my code to find.

Comment: If I understand you right, do you want to find all `<div>` that have `style="color: rgb(215, 218, 220);"` ?

Comment: no the part after that , it says 1, that is the upvote count.

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To get the text from an element with style that contains `rgb(215, 218, 220)`, you can use this example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page_html = '''
    <div class="_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO" style="color: rgb(215, 218, 220);">1</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

upvote_count = soup.select_one('div[style*="rgb(215, 218, 220)"]').text
print(upvote_count)
```

Prints:

```
1
```

Answer (score -1):

To find div element by class following approach can be used:

```
UpvoteCount = results.find('div', {"class": "_1rZYMD_4xY3gRcSS3p8ODO"})
```

To find all elements matching the condition use method findAll(). Returned is a list of elements found.